# How to Implement paste operation in DataGrid in WPF which is binded to a datatable?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am sure this must be implemented by someone. I have a Window which opens up and has a datagrid with 2 Columns namely Latitude and Longitude. The xaml is code is as follows:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG_UDTSet" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionMode="Extended" MinHeight="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="465" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="4">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="LeftAlignmentColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                </Style>

                <Style x:Key="CenterAlignmentColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>

                <Style x:Key="RightAlignmentColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Latitude" Binding="{Binding Path=Latitude}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterAlignmentColumnHeaderStyle}" Width="225"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Longitude" Binding="{Binding Path=Longitude}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterAlignmentColumnHeaderStyle}" Width="225"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

In the code behind an empty Data table is linked to the above Data grid. The code behind is as follows:

```
private DataTable UDTSInfo;
UDTSInfo = new DataTable();
UDTSInfo.Columns.Add("Latitude", typeof(Decimal));
UDTSInfo.Columns.Add("Longitude", typeof(Decimal));
this.DG_UDTSet.ItemsSource = UDTSInfo.DefaultView;
```

What I want to achieve is to copy multiple rows from excel containing Latitude and Longitude and paste in the above DataGrid.

Any help will be really appreciated as I am stuck and not able to find anything working. Also I don't want to use any third party dlls as it is needed to apply only in this DataGrid

Comment: I don't see here anything that you tried already. if you skip the excel part (which is the easiest part if you search a bit) then all you have to do is to create or update a row.

Comment: @Bizhan I did try lot of options available online but it wasn't working so I didn't post the code with them. If you can guide me or let me know any solution you have encountered, it would be of much help. Thanks!

Comment: As I said it's pretty straightforward, first read the data from excel, (then have a global command implemented to listen to Ctrl+V or not), then add a row with that data. I don't know in which part you have a problem and what exactly is the problem so right now I can't help you :)